# How can I make my C# app actually deploy with a copy of its SQLite database?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

I am working on a C# app which uses a SQLite database.

I have a connection string indicated in `app.config` which uses a relative path to target the database file.

The target relative to the project root is ./Data/MyDb.db

However, 2 things can happen based on my publish properties with VS publish menu:

Option 1:

In Project > Properties > Publish > Application Files, if I mark the publish status of /data/MyDb.db to "Include", when deploying the app, I have no idea where the database file is located. It does save and retrieve data successfully within the app, but I haven't got a clue of where these changes are being written, because the file in the installation folder `/Data/MyDb.db.deploy` **is not** storing them. I can add a new record and no modification is made to the file, but the app is still capable of retrieving the record, even after rebooting the pc, meaning that it is indeed saving the data somewhere.

Option 2:

if I mark the data/MyDb.db file publish status to "Data File" instead, when I deploy the app and write data in it, all of the data is stored in the SAME file that is in the folder of the development project. The deployment DOES NOT copy the file to its installation folder. This might not seem so inconvenient since at least I know where the changes are being written, but it seems cumbersome because I'd need to drag around the project folder wherever I want to install the application, when it should be completely independent.

Is there a way to either have the project actually copy the DB file into the installation folder or at least to determine where the live app is storing the changes? Or is there something I'm missing? Any better way to integrate the database?

Comment: Hi. Change the "Copy to Output Directory" attribute of the file to "copy if new". You could see it in the installation folder.

Comment: This action is unrelated to the problem. Copy to output directory merely copies the file to the bin folder when building the solution (which does happen) but it does not determine what gets copied to the installation folder after *publishing* the app. The problem is that the publishing feature seems to hide the actual database file where the app writes changes to.

Comment: Have you considered creating a static “SQLiteUtilities” Class and write the code to “create” the DB from scratch?

Comment: I waste a lot of hours until I found the solution.... incredible this question had no answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

There is no "visual option" and a lot of things can fail trying to resolve this.

`Copy to output`, as you well said, only works for debug things to the bin, not the publish.

If you don't tried anything, the solution "as is" is:

Open `.csproj` file and add the following:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataModelFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)..\YourProjectName\yourSQLiteFile.db" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(DataModelFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

Change only the directory and filename of the example, not any other thing. I used the project main directory but you can use other. I don't use a bin since that will copy my debug database, I need a new blank SQLite file.

**But BE AWARE:**

Is not required but will help to work:

- Include the file into the project
- Set it as "Copy always" and Content" from file properties.
- Check in the `.csproj` file if the file is not inside of groups like excluded files:

inside csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Remove="yourSQLiteFile.db" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You will try to include from the Visual Studio but it won't work, do nothing, you need to remove it from the file using a text editor like Notepad++